# How to associate id and its value in Combobox Domino designer(lotus script)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I am new to Domino designer and lotus script,

I have a form ,which has a combobox ,In combobox I have a formula for combobox:

```
(@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; ""; "myview"; 2)
```

now I want to associate the ID and its name

> Example : id :1  name(to display in combo) :Benz
>
> ```
>       id :2  name : Fiat
>       id :3  name : Yamaha
> ```

now my combobox must display only fiat,yamaha,benz but the corresponding id must be saved (not the name)

currently I'm displaying only names and saving names(I want to link it to id)

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view needs to contain the values in format Name|ID (this is a pipe sign) in order to achieve what you want.

Column values:

```
Benz|1
Fiat|2
Yamaha|3
```

Response to your comment: Best practice (performance- wise) is, to create a separate column in your view with the formula `Name + "|" + ID` (you can hide it, if you use the view for users AND DBColumn, what would be bad practice by the way).

if you don't want to do this, then your formula could look like this:

```
_names := @DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; ""; "myview"; 2);
_ids := @DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; ""; "myview"; 1);
_names + "|" + @Text(_ids)
```

You REALLY should take a training in Lotus Notes Design, as these are all basics, if you once understood how Notes works.

The formula above is bad in a lot ways:

1. Usage of "NoCache" is a real performance- killer. Don't do it in big applications
2. doing two lookups instead of one doubles your response- times
3. Every lookup HAS to have an error handling, otherwise your form will not open anymore, if there is an error in it.
4. If the return of your DBColumn is >32k of data (large lists) this whole thing will fail due to field restrictions in Lotus Notes

A "best practice" way to do this (ignoring the possible 32k error) would be:

Create a view with a (hidden) third column with formula `Name + "|" + ID`

Use this code:

```
_view := "myview";
_col := 3;
_lkp := @DBColumn( "" : "Cache" ; "" ; _view; _col );
@If( @IsError( _lkp ) ; "" ; _lkp )
```

Comment: In view I have two columns (id,values)   (@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; ""; "myview"; 2)(every row) + '|' + (@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; ""; "myview"; 1)(every row)  can I do like this ?

Comment: I know my code looks awkward , please tolerate ... I am a beginner to Domino designer and lotus script..

Comment: Thanks man , It's working great added @Text(for idLIST)   *since it is a number....:-)